# ¿Cómo hacer hover a los hermanos de un elemento sin tener en cuenta el espacio vacío del contenedor?

Tags: javascript, html, css, hover, opacity

Estoy intentando bajar la opacidad de los hermanos de un elemento al hacerle hover, intenté con css de la siguiente forma:

```
.parent:hover .child {
     opacity: .5;
}

.paren .child:hover {
     opacity: 1;
}
```

Pero como el contenedor está hecho con grid layout y está centrando el contenido, tiene un espacio vacío; al hacer hover sobre esa parte, cambia la opacidad de todos sus hijos. Logré acomodar este error utilizando js pero quería saber si existe una forma para hacerlo con CSS.

El HTML es:

```
 <main>
    <div class="wrapper"></div>
 </main>
```

y se le van agregando divs al .wrapper con la clase .card mediante js.

El CSS es:

```
:root {
  --card_width: 250px; 
  --row_increment: 10px;
  --card_border-color: #171010;
}

.wrapper {
  margin: 0 auto;
  width: 80%;
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(auto-fill, var(--card_width)); 
  grid-auto-rows: var(--row_increment);
  place-content: center; 
  align-items: center;
  column-gap: 30px;
  row-gap: 1px;
}

.card {
  position: relative;
  display: flex;
  transition: opacity 300ms ease-in-out;

  border: 3px solid var(--card_border-color);
  box-shadow: -7px 5px 10px 0px rgba(174,174,174, .1);
-webkit-box-shadow: -7px 5px 10px 0px rgba(174,174,174,0.1);
-moz-box-shadow: -7px 5px 10px 0px rgba(174,174,174,0.1);

  cursor: pointer;
}
```

Comment: Sería mejor que edites tu pregunta agregando tu HTML

Comment: Igual si tienes dudas sobre los selectores de sibilings, te recomendaría esta [lectura en medium](https://medium.com/free-code-camp/how-to-make-the-impossible-possible-in-css-with-a-little-creativity-bd96bb42b29d), también explican lo del selector `:not`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Lo más sencillo sería que usaras el selector [:not](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:not)

> La [pseudo-clase](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Pseudo-classes) CSS :not() representa elementos que no coinciden con una lista de selectores. Dado que impide que se seleccionen elementos específicos, se conoce como la pseudo-clase de negación.

```css
.child {
  background-color: rgb(200, 200, 200);
  padding: 5px;
  margin-bottom: 5px;
}

.parent:hover>.child:not(:hover) {
  opacity: 0.5;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <title>Document</title>
</head>

<body>
  <div class="parent">
    <div class="child">
      Hola mundo
    </div>
    <div class="child">
      Hola mundo
    </div>
    <div class="child">
      Hola mundo
    </div>
  </div>

</body>

</html>
```

Para el código anterior hay que notar que si sólo el padre tiene el *hover*, pero los hijos no, entonces todos los hijos tendrán un *opacity* de 0.5 así que ten cuidado. **¡Selecciona el padre inmediato!**

```css
.child {
  background-color: rgb(200, 200, 200);
  padding: 5px;
  margin-bottom: 5px;
}

.parent:hover>.child:not(:hover) {
  opacity: 0.2;
}

.parent {
  border: 5px solid #000;
  padding: 50px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <title>Document</title>
</head>

<body>
  <div class="parent">
    <div class="child">
      Hola mundo
    </div>
    <div class="child">
      Hola mundo
    </div>
    <div class="child">
      Hola mundo
    </div>
  </div>

</body>

</html>
```

Puedes poner que el *child* que no tenga *hover*, tenga opacidad de 0.5, pero esto hará que aunque no estés en esa parte todos tengan opacidad de 0.5 hasta que te posiciones sobre ese elemento, lo que no lo hace tan bonito a mi parecer

```
.child:not(:hover) {
    opacity: 0.5;
}
```

Comment: Funcionó excelente y la lectura que dejaste me ayudó a conocer mejor una útil herramienta. Muchas gracias 